# Can I schedule my Android phone to mute notifications of a specific app at specific times?

Tags: notifications, settings, automation

I don't want to receive work emails on weekends.

Can I schedule my Android phone to mute notifications of a specific app at specific times?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Can you be clear? You want to mute notifications of some apps or you don't want to receive emails? They are completely different questions? Or is it you want to mute notifications of your email app although they will still be received?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way is to enable "Don't Disturb" mode and adjust priorities so you can just receive notifications for the selected priority type on weekends for example